# Failed to start libvirtd.service: Unit -.mount is masked

Tags: qemu, kvm, libvirt

I've removed a disk (mounted at `/win-vm`) from host which had a kvm volume pool. Now I can't start `libvirtd`

```
root@ws:/# systemctl start libvirtd
Failed to start libvirtd.service: Unit -.mount is masked.
```

Logs

```
root@ws:/# journalctl -u libvirtd.service
-- Logs begin at Thu 2020-02-13 17:43:58 CET, end at Thu 2020-02-13 18:25:32 CET. --
Feb 13 17:45:24 ws systemd[1]: Starting Virtualization daemon...
Feb 13 17:45:24 ws systemd[1]: Started Virtualization daemon.
Feb 13 17:45:25 ws libvirtd[1157]: libvirt version: 5.0.0, package: 4 (Guido Günther <agx@sigxcpu.org> Mon, 17 Jun 2019 19:05:40 +0200)
Feb 13 17:45:25 ws libvirtd[1157]: hostname: ws
Feb 13 17:45:25 ws libvirtd[1157]: cannot open directory '/win-vm': No such file or directory
Feb 13 17:45:25 ws libvirtd[1157]: internal error: Failed to autostart storage pool 'win-vm': cannot open directory '/win-vm': No such file or directory
Feb 13 17:45:31 ws libvirtd[1157]: Failed to open file '/sys/class/net/veth0eac943/operstate': No such file or directory
Feb 13 17:45:31 ws libvirtd[1157]: unable to read: /sys/class/net/veth0eac943/operstate: No such file or directory
Feb 13 17:45:31 ws libvirtd[1157]: Failed to open file '/sys/class/net/veth725116c/operstate': No such file or directory
Feb 13 17:45:31 ws libvirtd[1157]: unable to read: /sys/class/net/veth725116c/operstate: No such file or directory
Feb 13 17:56:42 ws libvirtd[1157]: Cannot recv data: Connection reset by peer
Feb 13 17:56:42 ws libvirtd[1157]: Failed to connect socket to '/var/run/libvirt/virtlogd-sock': Connection refused
Feb 13 17:57:47 ws libvirtd[1157]: Failed to connect socket to '/var/run/libvirt/virtlogd-sock': Connection refused
Feb 13 17:57:47 ws libvirtd[1157]: Failed to connect socket to '/var/run/libvirt/virtlogd-sock': Connection refused
Feb 13 17:58:48 ws libvirtd[1157]: Failed to connect socket to '/var/run/libvirt/virtlogd-sock': Connection refused
Feb 13 17:58:48 ws libvirtd[1157]: Failed to connect socket to '/var/run/libvirt/virtlogd-sock': Connection refused
Feb 13 17:59:12 ws libvirtd[1157]: Failed to connect socket to '/var/run/libvirt/virtlogd-sock': Connection refused
Feb 13 17:59:12 ws libvirtd[1157]: Failed to connect socket to '/var/run/libvirt/virtlogd-sock': Connection refused
Feb 13 17:59:37 ws libvirtd[1157]: Failed to connect socket to '/var/run/libvirt/virtlogd-sock': Connection refused
Feb 13 17:59:37 ws libvirtd[1157]: Failed to connect socket to '/var/run/libvirt/virtlogd-sock': Connection refused
Feb 13 18:02:35 ws systemd[1]: Stopping Virtualization daemon...
Feb 13 18:02:35 ws systemd[1]: libvirtd.service: Succeeded.
Feb 13 18:02:35 ws systemd[1]: Stopped Virtualization daemon.
```

I've an empty `/win-vm` directory but logs say directory doesn't exist. Is there a workaround? Or can I start without checking volume pools?